# How to grep file with prefix pattern?

Tags: shell, grep

How can I grep for lines of a file wich start with a certain string?

For example, all lines with prefex `0x`, where the file has the lines

```
0x002
0x003
abc
```

Output should be

```
0x002
0x003
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
grep '^0x'
```

`^` means the starting of a line

e.g.

```
kent$  echo "0x002
0x003
abc
"|grep '^0x'
0x002
0x003
```